# Ada numbers code does not pass hidden test

Tags: c++, string

I did the "Ada numbers" problem on Codefights. My program did not pass 2 hidden tests. Can someone please look at my code and tell me the bugs? Thank you.

Here is the problem:

> Consider two following representations of a non-negative integer:
>
> 1) A simple decimal integer, constructed of a non-empty sequence of digits from 0 to 9;
>
> 2) An integer with at least one digit in a base from 2 to 16 (inclusive), enclosed between # characters, and preceded by the base, which can only be a number between 2 and 16 in the first representation. For digits from 10 to 15 characters a, b, ..., f and A, B, ..., F are used.
>
> Additionally, both representations may contain underscore (_) characters; they are used only as separators for improving legibility of numbers and can be ignored while processing a number.
>
> Your task is to determine whether the given string is a valid integer representation.

The length of the string must be between 1 and 30 (inclusive). There are a few test cases that my code has passed:

```
<p> "123_456_789" -> true
<p> "16#123abc#" -> true
<p> "10#123abc#" -> false
<p> "10#10#123ABC#" -> false
<p> "10#0#" -> true
<p> "10##" -> false
<p> "16#1234567890ABCDEFabcdef#" -> true
<p> "1600#" -> false
<p> "7#???#" -> false
<p> "4#4#" -> false
<p> "3454235ab534" -> false
<p> "1#0#" -> false
<p> "17#ac#" -> false
<p> "2#10110#" -> true
<p> "2#10110" -> false
<p> "#2#10110" -> false
<p> "#2#10110#" -> false
```

Here is my code:

```
bool adaNumber(std::string line) {
    bool bound1 = false, bound2 = false;
    int len = 0, base = 0;
    char numbers[50];
    char limits[] = {' ', ' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
    for (char c : line)
        if (c == '#') {
            if (len < 1)
                return false;
            if (bound1 && bound2)
                return false;
            numbers[len] = '\0';
            if (bound1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < strlen(numbers); ++i)
                    if (numbers[i] > limits[base])
                        return false;
                bound2 = true;
            }
            else {
                for (int i = 0; i < strlen(numbers); ++i) {
                    if (numbers[i] < '0' || numbers[i] > '9')
                        return false;
                    base = 10 * base + numbers[i] - '0';
                }
                if (base < 2 || base > 16)
                    return false;
                bound1 = true;
            }
            len = 0;
        }
        else if (('0' <= c && c <= '9') || ('a' <= c && c <= 'f') || ('A' <= c && c <= 'F')) {
            if (bound1 && bound2)
                return false;
            numbers[len++] = std::tolower(c);
        }
        else if (c != '_')
            return false;
    if (!bound1) {
        numbers[len] = '\0';
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(numbers); ++i)
            if (numbers[i] < '0' || numbers[i] > '9')
                return false;
        return true;
    }
    return bound2;
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: `Can someone please look at my code and tell me the bugs? ` Use a debugger

Comment: @user Can you give me the test case that it fails so that I can debug???? Did you read my whole post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. If the string contains only "_", it should be an invalid number representation. I just have to check that case, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't enjoy debugging other people's code much, so I hope you'll forgive me if I instead try to give some advice about how to solve this problem a little better.

Let's start by considering what allowable inputs look like. They're apparently either

```
decimal-digits
```

or:

```
decimal-digits '#' base-digits '#'
```

...where the base for `base-digits` is a number we pass as a parameter that supports bases from 2 to 16 (and the number we pass will be what's specified in the `decimal-digits` part, of course).

Although it's not stated directly, the test cases make it apparent that both the initial decimal number and (if present) the following based number must be non-empty for it to be considered a valid number.

Throughout the entire input, underscores are allowed but ignored, so it's probably easiest to just start by removing all of them.

Then we can look for a `#` in the input. This tells us which of the formats we need to parse. If there's no `#`, then it must be the first. Otherwise, it must be the second:

```
bool parse_num(std::string const &in) { 

    in.erase(std::remove(in.begin(), in.end(), '_'), in.end());

    std::string::size_t pos;
    if ((pos=in.find('#')) != std::string::npos)
        return parse_decimal(in);
    else
        return parse_based(in, pos);
}
```

Now, for parse_decimal, we just have to assure that it isn't empty, and every character in the string is a decimal digit:

```
bool parse_decimal(std::string const &in) {
    return !in.empty() && 
        std::all_of(
            in.cbegin(), in.cend(), 
            [](unsigned char c) { return std::isdigit(c); }
        );
}
```

Then we need to handle the more complex case: the number with a base specified.

So, the steps here are:

1. check that the part up to the `#` is a valid decimal number
2. check convert that part to a number
3. check that it's between 2 and 16 (inclusive)
4. check that the rest is a valid number in that base
5. check that there's a '#' to signal the end of the input number
6. Check that there's nothing following the '#'

Code for this might look something like this:

```
bool parse_based(std::string const &in, std::string::size_type sep) {
    std::string in_base = in.substr(0, sep);
    std::string in_num = in.substr(sep + 1);

    auto in_end = in_num.find('#');

    // needs to start with a valid decimal number and end with '#'
    if (!parse_decimal(in_base) || in_end != in_num.length()-1)
        return false;

    in_num = in_num.substr(0, in_end);

    int base = std::stoi(in_base);

    // Base must be between 2 and 16 inclusive
    if (base < 2 || base > 16)
        return false;

    return parse_based_num(in_num, base);
}
```

That leaves us with `parse_based_num`. This is pretty similar to `parse_decimal`, except that it accepts a base instead of assuming the base must be 10:

```
bool parse_based_num(std::string const &in, int base) {
    static const std::string digits = "0123456789abcdef";

    // Create a string of the digits allowed in the specified base:
    std::string allowed = digits.substr(0, base);

    return !in.empty() &&
        std::all_of(
            in.begin(), in.end(), 
            [&](unsigned char c) { return allowed.find(std::tolower(c)) !=std::string::npos; }
        );
}
```

If we wanted, we could re-write `parse_decimal` as something like `return parse_based_num(input, 10);`.

Two big takeways from this:

1. Scan not only the specifications, but also the tests to find requirements, and write down those requirements explicitly.
2. Break the problem down into understandable chunks--unless the problem is really trivial, you don't need to solve it in a single function.

In fairness, there are other ways this could be coded. For example, this could also be written pretty cleanly as a state machine (most parsing can).

Comment: Thank you for a very thoughtful comment. I did the way you said before, and my code didn't pass 2 hidden tests. I changed to a different style as seen in my question (my professor used this style in class; he called it "parsing" each character for easy debugging), but it couldn't pass 2 hidden tests either (not sure if they were the same tests because I wasn't allowed to see the tests). I believe if I can see the test case, I'm sure I can fix it.